# how to customize calendar in asp.net Core razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, calendar, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm working with .NET Core 3.1 web app and I have a model with date field like that:

`[DataType(DataType.Date)]`

`public DateTime availableDateToPick { get; set; }` .

and this model is viewed by Pages/Index like that:

```
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.availableDateToPick)
```

I can't figure out how to customize this calendar.
For example, I would like to grayed out some dates programmatically based on data base queries.
 as well as past dates, holidays dates and so on.

Comment: Not clear about your question.What do you mean `customize this calendar`?Do you want to show the dateTime in a calendar?

Comment: I mean to grayed out some dates (weekend , holidays, reserved days .. etc )